# A more elaborate way to explain my observations? (Determinant of a special matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I came across this nice result a long time ago and I'm having a hard time trying to prove it. I don't remember if I took it from a text book or if I came up with it myself. Any suggestions on how to prove the result will be welcome.

Consider the matrix $A_k$ with entries given by

$$ 
(a_k)_{ij} = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
i & i \geq j \\
j & i \leq j
\end{array}
\right.  
$$ for $(i,j) \in\{ 0, \ldots, k \} $ and $k \geq 0$. Then, I can verify numerically that 
$$\operatorname{det}(A_k) = (-1)^kk $$
For instance, here is $A_4$:

$$ A_4 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4
\end{array}
\right)$$ 
with $|A_4| = 4$. I notice that the computation of its determinant is straightforward, as only one term survives in the following sum
$|A_4| = 0\times 0 - 1 \times B_1 + 2 \times 0 - 3 \times 0 + 4 \times 0$, where $B_1$ is the matrix formed by substracting the first row and the second column from $A_4$. This is because the matrices $B_j$ (eliminate the first row and the $j$-th column from $A_4$) have two equal rows and two equal columns for $j > 1$. Therefore, the only contribution to $|A_4|$ comes from the determinant of $B_1$ which turns out to be $-4$, which can be *readily* seen by repeating the same reasoning.

Back in the days, I found this result quite interesting but now that I look further into it maybe it's not that thrilling. Is there a more mathematical approach to this result than my by-inspection solution?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtracting the second row from the first and so on:

$$A_4 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 &  -1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4
\end{array}
\right)\implies det(A_4)=(-1)^44$$

In general you can show the result by induction.

Comment: Ahhh, Gauss elimination. Great!